python struggling with basic math
python seams to be getting simple math's wrong. now i suck at python so im probably just missing something major
i am expecting it to print out the running total answer and print the sum then the answer. note this is a small script for a larger project
import random
answer = 0
trre = 0
bracket = 0
answer = 0
is_it_first = 0
lastop = "e"
#list with brackets
leist = [
#    "(",
    "+",
    "-"
]
#sets it to false
only1bracket = False
#lsit without brackets
lasit = [
    "+",
    "-"
]
#the list with the sum in it with start for debugging purpoises 
sume = [
    
]

while True:
    #generates the number and operaition does the sumber first for when its frist run
    n = random.randint(0, 9)
    e = random.choice(leist)
    sume.append(n)
    sume.append(e)
    #checks to see if it is the first time running the loop to set y to n to set up for finding the answer

    if lastop == "e":
        print("debug:first loop run")
    elif lastop == "+":
        answer = answer + n
        print("debug:" + str(answer))
    elif lastop == "-":
        answer = answer - n
        print("debug:" + str(answer))
    
    lastop = e
    trre += 1 
    is_it_first += 1
    if trre == 5:
        sume.pop()
        break

print(sume)

print(answer)


What's the output and why do you think it's wrong?

Also for a reproducible example you should code values you know produce the bug, not use random values.

the output was just the lasft number but i have fixed it in the last 20 min with simply adding answer = n in the first lastop if

[ask] and [mre]

Also, make sure you post changes in an [edit], not comments - comments are impermanent & also hard to read.

Don't blame Python - it's only doing exactly what you're telling it to. There is a discrepancy between what you think it should be doing, and what you're telling it to do.
It seems your code is supposed to generate a simple arithmetical expression with five terms, such as:
9 + 7 - 2 - 8 - 9
Followed by the answer:
-3
However, your code produces the result:
-12

To understand why, let's step through it, line-by-line:

Pick a random number (9)
Pick a random operator (+)
Append both to sume ([9, +])
lastop is equal to "e", so we don't modify answer
Set lastop to the random operator we chose in step 2 (+)
Advance to the next iteration of the loop
Pick a random number (7)
Pick a random operator (-)
Append both to sume ([9, +, 7, -])
lastop is equal to + (from step 5), so we set answer to 7 (answer = 0 + 7). Notice how our very first random number (9) is not going to end up influencing answer at all.
Set lastop to the random operator we chose in step 8 (-)
Advance to the next iteration of the loop
Pick a random number (2)
Pick a random operator (-)
Append both to sume ([9, +, 7, -, 2, -])
lastop is equal to - (from step 11), so we set answer to 5 (answer = 7 - 2)
Set lastop to the random operator we chose in step 14 (-)
Advance to the next iteration of the loop
Pick a random number (8)
Pick a random operator (-)
Append both to sume ([9, +, 7, -, 2, -, 8, -])
lastop is equal to - (from step 17), so we set answer to -3 (answer = 5 - 8)
Set lastop to the random operator we chose in step 20 (-)
Advance to the next iteration of the loop
Pick a random number (9)
Pick a random operator (-)
Append both to sume ([9, +, 7, -, 2, -, 8, -, 9, -])
lastop is equal to - (from step 23), so we set answer to -12 (answer = -3 - 9)
Set lastop to the random operator we chose in step 26 (-)
trre is equal to 5, pop the last item from sume (which is now [9, +, 7, -, 2, -, 8, -, 9]), and end the loop.
answer is -12


The problem is basically in step 4. Your very first random number does not contribute to answer at all, and is essentially skipped.
